# How to switch a div display on first click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

html head:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">

    function getStyle() {
        var temp = document.getElementById("cont").style.display;
        return temp;
    }

    function switch01() {
        var current = getStyle();
        if (current == "none") {
            document.getElementById("cont").style.display = "block";
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("cont").style.display = "none";
        }
    }​

</script>
```

body:

```
<a href="javascript:switch01('cont')">CONTENT</a>
```

CSS:

```
#cont{
    display: none;
}
```

After loading the page - first click doesn't work. After the first click - everything works.
Also, How could I show/hide the div slowly (with sliding effect, not momentally) ?

Comment: If you want "effects" and movement, you should take a look at jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the slide effect, my recommendation is using jQuery:

```
$('#toggle').click(function() {
    $('#cont').slideToggle();
});​
```

See this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3kKkD/3/).

For changing the sliding speed and more information see [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/).

Answer (score 5):

The value you get for the first time is "undefined".

You can:

1) Set the value via javascript when page loads;

```
document.getElementById("cont").style.display = "none";
```

or

2) decode "undefined" value to none, because you know that at first the value will be none;

```
var temp = document.getElementById("cont").style.display;
if (temp == "undefined") 
   temp = "none";
return temp;
```

both pretty ugly solutions, but they work.

Answer (score 3):

If it must be inline you need to do this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/kwzAg/)

```
<a href="#" onclick="return switch01('cont')">CONTENT</a>
```

and this (reversing the test for none to be a test for not block)

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
function switch01(objId) {
  var current = document.getElementById(objId).style.display;
  document.getElementById(objId).style.display=(current!="block")?"block":"none";
  return false
}
</script>
```

The above ANSWERS your question

**UPDATE**: Since it seems you would like jQuery instead, here is how you need to code that - notice the return false which Michal missed.

```
<a href="#" id="toggle">CONTENT</a>

$(function() { // wait for the page to load
  $('#toggle').on("click",function(e) { // when link clicked
    $('#cont').slideToggle(); // slide open or closed
    return false; // or e.preventDefault(); // stop the click executing the href
  });​
});​
```

Comment: maybe document.getElementById(objId).style.display=(current!="block")?"block":"none"; will work for the first time too, starting with none... i guess

Comment: Yes. My thoughts. Just had to jsfiddle it to see wheich one works

Comment: Thanks a lot to everyOne. Solved.

Comment: Comparing with different: definitely the neatest solution :)

Comment: Rules on SO should be changed. We have more than one correct answers, but only one is possible to accept.

Comment: I agree. Whichever looks the most like what you ended up using should be the answer - if identical, then the oldest in my opinion. In this case I did NOT suggest the simpler jQuery because you did not tag your question with jQuery and did not have any jQuery in the post

Answer (score 1):

For hiding the div.. you can take a look at

```
     $('cont').hide(); function.
```

More relevant Information is available here :

```
     http://api.jquery.com/hide/

     http://api.jquery.com/show/
```

And for sliding effect Jquery is top notch in this department. You just have to pass the argument as given below.. and it does the work.

```
     $("cont").click(function () {
         $(this).hide("slide", { direction: "down" }, 1000);
     });
```

FYI : http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Slide